# No textContent when getting value by xPath Puppeteer

Tags: node.js, reactjs, puppeteer

I'm trying to get the text inside of my `value` div with id `staked` (397.497836). It looks like this:

[image]

I'm coping the xpath of the element, which is: `//*[@id="staked"]`

In all of the examples i've seen on stackoverflow/github it seems that people are able to retrieve the text using `textContent` however my logging doesn't show that field available.

```
await page.waitForXPath('//*[@id="staked"]');
let handle = await page.$x('//*[@id="staked"]');
console.log(handle[0]);

 _remoteObject: {
    type: 'object',
    subtype: 'node',
    className: 'HTMLDivElement',
    description: 'div#staked.value',
    objectId: '-6241729959890640645.3.7'
  },
```

For context, this isn't static text, as i'm passing it from my React component. Any ideas how I could do this differently to obtain the text?

Comment: What's the point of using an xpath when you have the id? `page.$("#staked")` seems easier, and if you want the text, it's the normal way, `page.$eval("#staked", el => el.textContent))`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to get text inside div in puppeteer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55237748/how-to-get-text-inside-div-in-puppeteer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

now you need to extract that value from the handle with [.evaluate](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args)

and as ggorlen pointed out, you can use id:

```
// xpath
const el = await page.waitForXPath('//*[@id="staked"]');
const content1 = await el.evaluate(el => el.textContent);
console.log('xpath', content1);

// id
const content2 = await page.$eval("#staked", el => el.textContent);
console.log('id', content2);
```

Comment: This was something I had tried prior my issue actually was that I had to sleep for roughly a second before the values actually were there as prior to that a spinning GIF logo was in the spot. Appreciate the help.